# How to definitely replace componentWillReceiveProps and keep getting the nextProps?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am running React 16.8.4 in my App and I really need to use nextProps in some cases. As React Docs mention, componentWillReceiveProps is an UNSAFE method an is not recommended to use it anymore.
I read the Docs (https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#recommendation-fully-uncontrolled-component-with-a-key) but I don't even know how to port my old componentWillReceiveProps using this version with keys and everything.
I don't need to create a new component instance, I just need nextProps!!!
I tried to use componentDidUpdate(), but i don't want to get the prevProps, **I WANT NEXT PROPS**!
Could you guys help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`this.props` in `componentDidUpdate` will be the same as `nextProps` in `componentWillReceiveProps`, so you could use that.

```
// componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
//   if (nextProps.someProp !== this.props.someProp) {
//     doSomething();
//   }
// }

componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (this.props.someProp !== prevProps.someProp) {
    doSomething();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getDerivedStateFromProps` instead of `componentWillReceiveProps`.

Comment: Could you add a little context please ? Is it exactly the same ?